# Android Studio: Creating user types

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm writing to ask for some advice for my application. I've only ever created an application whereby a user registers and logs in.

However, I'm trying to create an app where there are two user types: landlord and tenant. The only way I can think to do this is to create two different databases and with two different login screens to allow the user to access the correct activity. I can't help but feel this way of doing it is a long and arduous one.

I was wondering if anyone could point me into a better direction in terms of logging in with unique user types?

**Edits**
*Figure 1*

```
public boolean validateUser(String username, String password){
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
                    + KEY_USERS + "='" + username +"'AND "+KEY_PASS+"='"+password+"'" ,  null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit "general" or in other words I don't have a good idea of what exactly is your app supposed to do. Anyways. I would suggest the following:
You can create a field (let's call this field "TYPE") in your database that will hold a value (e.g true/false or whatever serves your purpose) that will differentiate between the 2 types of users. In your login activity you will access the user and check the "TYPE" field and according to the value in the field you will start the appropriate activity.

For Example:

- User logs in ->

  - If value == true -> Start tenant activity
  - Else ->
    Start landlord activity

Comment: I apologise for my vagueness. In my application, I am asking an SQLite database for the user validation. I can check that the user is listed in the DB as so: (included in update, see figure 1). I just can't figure out how to check whether the user is a landlord or tenant

Comment: Yeah, exactly! IMO my suggestion should solve your problem. First of all create new field (column) in your database. E.g if you now have "ID"|"NAME"|"PASS"| add another column "TYPE". This field can hold whatever value you like but since you have only tenant and landlord I suggested true/false as the possible values. After that you could check with your cursor if the field is true or false the following way: 
`String type = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("TYPE") );` 
Check if type is true or false and after that you can start the appropriate activity accordingly.